# Cannot login to GUI

Tags: drivers, login, gui, gpu

I have processor: AMD Ryzen 7 7700X (integrated GPU)
And mainboard: MSI MPG X670E CARBON WIFI Socket AM5

I cannot login to GUI interface when I type password it goes back to login page.

I tried this manual to install GPU drivers, but none of these methods worked for me:
https://linuxconfig.org/amd-radeon-ubuntu-20-04-driver-installation

From this article command `dmesg` asks for permission.

```
dmesg | grep -i amdgpu
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
```

But when I run it with `sudo` it returns nothing.

How can I fix this issue? Install these drivers properly?

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Actually `dmesg` shows now bunch of stuff, which I don't understand.

I am trying to start GUI from commandline but there is error, which I can't copy or pass to file using `sudo startx >> log`

This error says: `xinit: connextion to X server lost`

I took it from `stderr`:

```
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Current Operating System: Linux gkucmierz-MS-7D70 6.2.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Oct  6 10:23:26 UTC 2 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-35-generic root=UUID=64bb09e9-526f-4d78-a7e5-cb7dffd9144e ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
xorg-server 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.2.log", Time: Mon Oct 23 04:39:32 2023
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

This is `/var/log/Xorg.2.log` log file:

https://justpaste.it/2i8pf - it is too big to paste it here.